# Query on upload to s3 bucket NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have one doubt about the s3 bucket; while uploading data to the s3 bucket using the upload function from aws-sdk in NodeJS, is data uploaded securely using TLS?

Comment: Also consider enabling the AWS Config rule [s3-bucket-ssl-requests-only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-ssl-requests-only.html) to be sure that all S3 bucket policies require encryption during data transit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js 12 and later use a minimum version of OpenSSL 1.1.1b, which **supports TLS 1.3**. The AWS SDK for JavaScript v3 defaults to use TLS 1.3 when available, but defaults to a lower version if required.

To get the current version of TLS used by Node.js on your machine, start the Node shell and run the following script:

```js
const tls = require("tls")
tlsSocket = new tls.TLSSocket()
protocol = tlsSocket.getProtocol()
console.log(protocol)
```

#### References:

- [Verify the version of OpenSSL and TLS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/enforcing-tls.html)

Comment: No need to use `var` anymore in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can enforce your bucket to accept only TLS connections by adding the following bucket policy,

```
{
  "Id": "ExamplePolicy",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowSSLRequestsOnly",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET",
        "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```